# Is anyone sure of the requirements to take Eurostar from London to Netherlands after 23 January 2021

Tags: paperwork, covid-19, netherlands, eurostar

I am a British citizen but a permanent resident of the Netherlands, hoping to take the Eurostar from London to Amsterdam on 26 January.

The Netherlands has of course implemented extremely strict travel restrictions between UK and NL but the train seems to be running, and I meet the exemption criteria to travel.

However, I am unsure about the requirements, especially about the "rapid antigen test". Dutch and British government websites state that this is required only for entry by flight or boat, and Eurostar website asks only for 72 hour PCR test. But some small news websites in NL report that the 4 hour rapid test is also required.

Does anyone know what will be required to board the train?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Eurostar has updated its website and now has the latest details! Both a PCR test (max 72 hours before departure) *and a rapid test* (max 4 hours before departure) are required for travel to the Netherlands.

Eurostar recommends this clinic: https://www.privatecoronavirustests.com/page/how-does-the-test-work (clinic is 10 mins away by tube, with results in 15-20 minutes verbally and a certificate to arrive within an hour).

Comment: Can you link to that specific page? Double-checked, and the Dutch government still only mentions the rapid test for air and sea travel

Comment: Found it. Going to enquire with the Dutch KMar

Comment: Yep, guess you found it but here: https://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/travel-info/service-information/eurostar-travel-updates

Comment: Thanks. I told the KMar that either the government website is wrong or Eurostar is incorrectly informed, and that in the latter case, Eurostar should be urgently notified to avoid people being wrongfully denied boarding. Still waiting for a reply

Comment: Also didn't see it on the Dutch government website, called the Dutch embassy in the UK and they were confused too, but they think the rapid antigen test is required. On this web page, it specifically says that only a PCR test is required for train travel https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/coronavirus-covid-19/reizen-en-vakantie/verplichte-negatieve-covid-19-testuitslagen so all very confusing.

Comment: Interested to hear what response you get from KMar, good idea!

Comment: In general I can say that at the external Schengen border it's checked by the KMar, for Schengen flights by regional security officers, and at the land border+Eurostar by train/bus staff. At the land border tests are only required for long-distance trains/buses, so for regional trains/buses from Belgium/Germany no test is required at all. Anyway, the KMar is usually quick, so I'll get back to you ASAP

Comment: Just got the reply that the rapid test is required. Terrible for the government website to be inaccurate. I'll have them make sure it's updated to say "air, sea and Eurostar"

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, and for your fact finding work on this one! Have also tried to contact them, hopefully they can clarify. Stay safe!

Comment: Did you locate their email address (it's not published online)? You want kcc.kmar@mindef.nl (that's the KMar at the national level)